# XML package that convert xml/schema file into classes representation with open license

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, codesynthesis, tinyxml2

I'm looking for open source package in c++/python that can parse an xml file of schema file (.xsd), and load it into classes based formation so i can easily set/get any field/attribute/etc ... in the document.

I've looked in tinyxml2 and Apache xml project and haven't found exactly what i'm looking for ...

http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/ is the best solution but the license is GPL2 which doesn't work for me.

appreciate you help !